# Saving data in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uitextview, saving-data

I'm writing notes app for iOS and I want all data which user enter in notes will be automatically saved when user typing automatically. I'm using Core Data and now I save data on viewWillDisappear, but I want the data also be saved if user terminate the app or the app will be automatically terminated in the background.

I use this code:

```
    import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddEditNotes: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    var note: Note!
    var notebook: Notebook?
    var userIsEditing = true

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        if (userIsEditing == true) {
            textView.text = note.text!
            title = "Edit Note"
        }
        else {
            textView.text = ""
        }


    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if (userIsEditing == true) {
            note.text = textView.text!
        }
        else {
            self.note = Note(context: context)
            note.setValue(Date(), forKey: "dateAdded")
            note.text = textView.text!
            note.notebook = self.notebook
        }

        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Note Saved!")
    }
        catch {
            print("Error saving note in Edit Note screen")
        }
    }



}
```

I understand what I can use applicationWillTerminate for this, but how I can pass there the data user entered? This functionality is in default notes app from Apple. But how it can be released?

Comment: Don't wait until the last moment to save your data. Save it as soon as it becomes available.

Comment: So do you propose to use textViewDidChange delegate method?

Comment: You can save on did end editing

Comment: But in this way if I use textViewDidEndEditing and app will be suddenly terminated if user type text, data will not be saved.

Comment: If this is so important you can save it on did change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two subtasks to saving the data: updating the Core Data entity with the contents of the text view and saving the Core Data context.

To update the contents of the Core Data entity, add a function to the `AddEditNotes` class that saves the text view contents.

```
func saveTextViewContents() {
    note.text = textView.text
    // Add any other code you need to store the note.
}
```

Call this function either when the text view ends editing or the text changes. If you call this function when the text changes, the Core Data entity will always be up to date. You won't have to pass the data to the app delegate because the app delegate has the Core Data managed object context.

To save the Core Data context, add a second function to the `AddEditNotes` class that saves the context.

```
func save() {
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        appDelegate.saveContext()
    }
}
```

This function assumes you selected the Use Core Data checkbox when you created the project. If you did, the app delegate has a `saveContext` function that performs the Core Data save.

You can now replace the code you wrote in `viewWillDisappear` with the calls to the two functions to save the text view contents and save the context.

The last code to write is to go to your app delegate file and add the following line of code to the `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillTerminate` functions:

```
self.saveContext()
```

By adding this code your data will save when someone quits your app.

Comment: Thanks for your solution and good answer! I already made saving notes in textViewDidChange as user type every symbol. May be your solution will be more correct.